# Passing parameter via Azure Databricks Notebook URL

Tags: python, azure, powerbi, adb, databricks

So my requirement is as follows:

I have a PowerBI report which has list of IDs, I want to pass that ID as a parameter over ADB python notebook URL. I will create a measure which will append ID to the end of ADB notebook URL and when the user clicks on the URL they will be directed to the ADB notebook. In the ADB notebook I will fetch the ID from the url and do data manipulation based on the particular ID. Any better way to accomplish this task, I tried appending the ID at the end of ADB notebook, but it does not seems to be an ideal solution.

Any recommendations will be helpful.

NOTE: I do not want fetch the data directly to PowerBI, everything needs to be done in ADB itself.

Comment: does appending the ID at the end of the notebook link work at all?

Comment: Asking the same question. Did you ever find out?

Answer (score -1):

When I need to pass parameters to a Databricks notebook I use widgets. Usually I pass the parameters using Data Factory. I never done it  with Power BI. You can create a simple widget with the code bellow

```
dbutils.widgets.dropdown("X", "1", [str(x) for x in range(1, 10)])
```

You also can check the documentation with the code

```
dbutils.widgets.help()
```

Comment: question was about passing arguments via URL, widgets are for different thing